# In InDesign, is it possible to hide the Web Content loading icon?

Tags: adobe-indesign, icon, animation, ipad

I am using web content layouts to make sure my animations are shown on the iPad. If I display the magazine on an iPad, I can see a loading icon on opening the page, right before the animation starts. Is it possible to remove this loading icon?

Comment: I don't know. But what I know is, that loading animations are a good thing for users to see that something is happening. If you take away the loading button one could think the ipad has frozen. So from a usability point of view I would keep the animation.

Comment: I have several animations happening at the same moment. Loading takes less than a second but long enough to notice the loading icon. I get your point but since I have a lot of small animations it just really takes away the beauty. You wouldn't see those loading icons if you'd use the native animations. But I can't use them because I wan't these animations to work on iPads.

Comment: Can you push the animations off the page while they load, so they're somewhere OFFSCREEN until they're loaded and ready to play? Use like an "OnLoaded" to change their rightful position when they're ready. Alternatively, can they be Z-order hidden until loaded?

Comment: Flying in animations show a centered loading icon. It's an interesting idea though. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Are you using one of the other Adobe HTML motion apps to create your animations?

Comment: Yes, Adobe Edge, but I also tried to create the animation myself

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the answer is no. I haven't seen this mentioned in any documentation online.